# Do I need to dispose Pixmap in Actor?

Tags: libgdx, kotlin

I create Pixmap in Actor and don't know how to dispose it. Is it necessary in my case?

```
class MyActor(x: Float = 0f, y: Float = 0f): Actor() {

    var pixmap = Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
    var texture = Texture(pixmap)
    var sprite = Sprite(texture)

    init {
        setPosition(x, y)
        sprite.setSize(32f, 32f)
        sprite.setPosition(this.x - sprite.width/2, this.y - sprite.height/2)
    }

    override fun act(delta: Float) {
        sprite.setPosition(x - sprite.width/2, y - sprite.height/2)
    }

    override fun draw(batch: Batch?, parentAlpha: Float) {
        sprite.draw(batch)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As other answer stated, in this case it is fine to dispose the Pixmap right after the Texture creation.

However, (especially) if you are on Android (but elsewhere too), you should load your Textures via [AssetManager](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Managing-your-assets), as Android may discard your textures when application switches to background and AssetManager takes care of reloading them.

Also, if you end up creating more than one instance of `MyActor` (which you probably will, by the looks of it), you should share the texture between them:

```
val blankTexture = run {
    val pixmap = Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
    val texture = Texture(pixmap)
    pixmap.dispose();
    texture
}

class MyActor(x: Float = 0f, y: Float = 0f): Actor() {

    val sprite = Sprite(blankTexture)
    ...
```

Edit:

Example with AssetManager:

- Create 1x1 image file and store it in your assets (or you can download [this one](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/tests/gdx-tests-android/assets-raw/skin/white.png) from libGDX repository)
- Create AssetManager and load the texture (and everything else you need)

```
class MyGame : ApplicationAdapter {

    companion object {
        lateinit var assetManager:AssetManager
        lazyinit var white: Texture
    }

    override fun create() {
        // Create new AssetManager (I am assuming here that this method will be called only once per game lifecycle)
        assetManager = AssetManager()
        // Preload the texture
        assetManager.load("white.png", Texture::class.java)
        // Make sure that it is loaded
        assetManager.finishLoading()
        // Cache it into a variable
        white = assetManager.get("white.png", Texture::class.java)
    }

    fun dispose() {
        assetManager.dispose()
    }
}
```

- Use that texture in your actor

```
class MyActor(x: Float = 0f, y: Float = 0f): Actor() {
    val sprite = Sprite(MyGame.white)
    ...
}
```

Note: As the wiki article about AssetManager mentions, static variables on Android (or in the case of Kotlin - `object`s) are somewhat tricky. But as long as you reinitialize them all when the game starts (in `create()` or somewhere similar) you should be fine. (That is why I used `lateinit var` instead of `val`.)

This solution is a quite bit more verbose and completely sidesteps the original question about Pixmap. If you are making only a small learning project without any other textures, or don't target Android, feel free to stay with the original AssetManager-less solution.

Comment: So, you mean I should store 1x1 pixel Texture or Pixmap in AssetManager?

Comment: I have edited my answer. AssetManager generally doesn't store Pixmaps and loads resources from files instead. But to answer: Store the `Texture` in the `AssetManager` - by letting `AssetManager` load it into itself.

Answer (score 0):

Its safe to dispose the pixmap straight after creating a texture from it as its no longer needed.

```
var pixmap = Pixmap(1, 1, Pixmap.Format.RGBA8888)
var texture = Texture(pixmap)
pixmap.dispose();
var sprite = Sprite(texture)
```